# Scraping from javascript in HTML tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the names from all the alphabets (Ato Z and also 0-9) of this website http://www.smfederation.org.sg/membership/members-directory

But the names seems to be hidden in `href ="javascript:void(0)"`

Below is my code

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.smfederation.org.sg/membership/members-directory"
for item in url:
    detail = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(detail.content, 'html.parser')
```

I have no idea how to approach javascript with in HTML.
What should i add to the above code to fetch the names of all listings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scraping the wrong url. Open the inspector of your browser, go to the Network tab and you will see that the names are at http://smfederation.org.sg/account/getaccounts

It's in json format, so it will automatically be a Python dictionary when you load it using the `.json()` method of the response object returned by `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> accounts = requests.get("http://www.smfederation.org.sg/account/getaccounts").json()
>>> accounts["data"][0]["accountname"]
'OPTO-PRECISION PTE LTD'
```

You can also get all accounts using a `for` loop, such as:

```
for account in accounts["data"]:
    print(account["accountname"])
```

Comment: That is really helpful !! Thank you so much !!